# Are there palindrome-like constructs in written Cree?

Tags: language-games

I just learned about [Cree syllabics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cree_syllabics) from a comment on another SE. According to the wiki (emphasis mine)

> Canadian Aboriginal syllabics are unique among abugida scripts in that the orientation of a symbol, rather than modifications of its shape or diacritic marks, determines the vowel of a syllable. Each basic shape corresponds to a specific consonant sound; this is **flipped or rotated** to denote the accompanying vowel.

For example, the glyphs ᑕ, ᑌ, ᑎ, and ᑐ represent the syllables *ta*, *te*, *ti*, and *to*, respectively.

English has palindromes and words that look the same upside down when written in a certain case and font, e.g., "pod". But the typography of Cree syllabics opens up whole new possibilities for palindrome-like constructs. For example, you could potentially have text in a 2D grid that reads intelligibly but differently depending on the orientation of the page.

Do such texts exist? Are there any well-known examples?

Comment: Interesting question! Unfortunately, about half of the characters are flipped rather than rotated, which restricts your choice of words severely. But it would still be easier than in English.